# Mongoengine LongField Overflow Error

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I have a Text model;

```
class Text(db.Document):
    siphash_value = db.LongField()
```

Then I use siphash lib for create a hash.(https://github.com/majek/pysiphash)

This lib converts string to long value like **12398370950267227270L**

If I try save document to my db;

```
Text(siphash_value=12398370950267227270L).save()
```

I get this error:

```
OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints
```

Comment: I'm using now this lib https://github.com/bozhu/siphash-python and working perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB only supports 64 bit integers ([bson.spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)) so pymongo can't convert the Long hence the error.

Comment: So I had to use crc32 algorithm rather than siphash.

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell us WHY it is working now? The new library is returning a non long field? (I can not comment your own answer because I have less than 50 reputation, sorry all).

I tried to replace LongField by FloatField and it worked. And actually it has the same result.
Just had a different notation (1.2398370950267228e+19).

Comment: So whichever is faster in speed? FlotField vs LongField ?

Comment: FloatField is 64 bits wide, so the number is just an approximation of your original number.